# Rebol doesn't work with localhost

Tags: rebol

When doing

```
read http://localhost
```

or

```
read http://127.0.0.1
```

read returns empty string

why ?

Update : finally I know why it doesn't work see my own answer below.

Comment: Is RebolTutorial back?  :)  In any case, both work for me *(without the "g" in 12g7.0.0.1 of course... corrected)*.  Using the build from http://rebolsource.net

Comment: Carl was asking about you at the http://recode.revault.org conference! We miss you!!! :)
It worked for me on both Rebol 2 and 3. The problem should be with the server side; sending something irregular. Try `trace true`.

Comment: Do you have any local webserver running? I have no problem reading from localhost.

Comment: What about if you type http://localhost on your browser? Do you get any content?

Comment: @HostileFork yeah I try to setup reboltutorial.net with Openshift :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18293757/add-second-cname-for-openshift

Comment: @rebolek sure I have a wordpress blog with portable apache http://sourceforge.net/projects/miniserver/files/MiniServer/MiniServer_%20Wordpress/

Comment: @endo64 yes it shows my wordpress blog

Comment: @onetom really I can't believe it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Finally It's because I put some special code to detect localhost as explained in my own tutorial I didn't remember then :)

https://tutorial-rebol.rhcloud.com/how-to-detect-rebol-referer-in-a-php-script/

> Remark that It is necessary to test $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] which
>   allows to know if rebol call is coming from the remote client or from
>   the local cgi so as to avoid infinite loop.

Comment: All's well that ends well, but perhaps this question should be deleted?  I believe you as the question author can initiate that process.  In any case, we have a stackoverflow chat group, [please join us](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol-and-red)