# Add second cname for openshift

Tags: dns, openshift

I have successfully customize domain with

```
rhc alias add tutorial reboltutorial.net
rhc alias add tutorial www.reboltutorial.net
```

Problem is I cannot add

```
CNAME   .reboltutorial.net  tutorial-rebol.rhcloud.com
```

to my current DNS records

```
A   reboltutorial.net   198.XXX.YYY.ZZZ NA  3600        
CNAME   www.reboltutorial.net   tutorial-rebol.rhcloud.com
```

So is it possible to add both domain.com and www.domain.com to Openshift ?

Update : well finally even without adding 2nd Cname [reboltutorial.net](http://reboltutorial.net) works though I don't understand how if someone can explain to me :)

Comment: Yes that should be possible. This is standard domain name system (DNS) configuration.

Answer (score 2):

No that is not possible. You are trying to point an A record ( reboltutorial.net) to a URL and this is not allowed.

Some DNS providers to what is called naked domain forwarding and so you could then point your A record to a C record or direct to the URL.

More is explained in this blog post

https://www.openshift.com/blogs/custom-url-names-for-your-paas-applications-host-forwarding-and-cnames-the-openshift-way

Comment: So naked domains are not possible with OpenShift?

Comment: they are if your DNS provider supports them

Comment: Great - you all set? Did the blog post answer your question?

Comment: actually it was the Openshift IRC who helped me. Nevertheless the blog post was helpful.